# CakePHP request params action

Tags: cakephp

I am learning CakePHP and just come across this :
       `$action=$this->request->params[‘action’]` in Controller class. 
Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: taking the `action` request (GET or POST) param, is that what you asking?

Comment: I saw the exact line I have copied here with the word ‘action’ . No GET or POST were written

Comment: hope it's clear now :)

Comment: Sorry @Alex , it s not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Cake, the request object exposes route elements such as the controller name, action name, and passed arguments. We access these elements by using the `getParam()` method on the request object or by using the params array on the request object as you have done.

So if we go to the url `http://somedomain/posts/update/3` the request object will contain the following data via `getParam` or the param array:

- `$this->request->params['controller']` (PostsController)
- `$this->request->params['action']` (index)

Please see [Request Object](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#request-parameters) and [Route Elements](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#route-elements) for more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $this->request->getParam('controller')
> ```

OR

> ```
> $this->request->getParam('action')
> ```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - the OP asked explicitly about such an explanation